# How to define arrays in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a following snippet of the code shown below. I want that after execution of the code, the original array values(like x1, x2, y1 and y2 array etc) be changed accordingly, which currently is not happening. Is there any way to do this ??. Like currently after the execution of the code, the x1 array values remain unchanged, I want that they should be changed accordingly as list1[0] array value gets changed after execution of the code.

```
import numpy as np
x1=np.array([10,2,10,5,10,7,10,6])
y1=np.array([2,3,6,5,8,9,7,8])
r1=np.array([0,4,0,3,0,5,0,3])
x2=np.array([10,3,10,6,10,8,10,7])
y2=np.array([2,3,6,5,8,9,7,8])
r2=np.array([0,5,0,7,0,9,0,3])
list1=[x1,x2]
list2=[y1,y2]
list3=[r1,r2]
for plane in range(0,2):
    x=list1[plane]
    y=list2[plane]
    r=list3[plane]
    comb=np.array([x,y,r])
    comb=np.transpose(comb)
    combsort=comb[np.argsort(comb[:,0])]
    combsort=combsort.transpose()
    x=combsort[0]
    y=combsort[1]
    r=combsort[2]
    ind1=np.where(x==10)
    ind2=ind1[0]
    if(ind2.size):
        indd=ind2[0]
    x[indd:indd+len(ind2)]=np.ones(len(ind2))
    y[indd:indd+len(ind2)]=np.ones(len(ind2))
    r[indd:indd+len(ind2)]=np.ones(len(ind2)) 
    list1[plane]=x
    list2[plane]=y
    list3[plane]=r
    
print(x1)   
print(list1[0])
```

Output

```
[10  2 10  5 10  7 10  6]
[2 5 6 7 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Can you build a more minimal [mre]? If you can build, say, three lines of code that demonstrate (1) an array being created; (2) that array having something done that ought to change it; (3) that array not being changed -- that would be a lot easier to follow than trying to reverse-engineer your code to figure out what was in mind when it was written.

Comment: Assigning to a list element replaces the object that was there, it doesn't modify the object in place.

Comment: @ Barmar, is there an another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's [column stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
np.column_stack((x1, y1))
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler case:

```
In [63]: x=np.array([1,2,3])
In [64]: alist = [x]
In [65]: alist
Out[65]: [array([1, 2, 3])]
In [66]: alist[0]
Out[66]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [67]: alist[0][:] = [4,5,6]     # this changes elements of the array
In [68]: alist
Out[68]: [array([4, 5, 6])]
In [69]: x
Out[69]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

this changes the element of the list - to a list with a different size

```
In [70]: alist[0]=[7,8]
In [71]: alist
Out[71]: [[7, 8]]
In [72]: x
Out[72]: array([4, 5, 6])
```